# GMGridView ios 5.1 and lower issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, scrollview, gmgridview

First of all this question is oriented on those who practiced [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) with iOS 5.0+

I have GridView's cell as a separate screen with some components (buttons, tableView with custom cells) on it.
The problem is that in ios 6+ I can get access to that components (button's click actions and so on) but not in 5.0 and 5.1.
In this case when I try to interact with screen (cell) the method

```
- (void)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView didTapOnItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)position
```

is called with the same "position" (actually, it shows the number of current cell). But in ios6+ this method's never called.
The question is - how can I make components on the gridView cell active on ios 5.0 as on ios 6+?

If any additional info needed - please ask

Regards.

P.S. I post the same issue here because on Github's repo page i can't see any activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was just add the following code to GMGridView.m

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
 if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
 {
    return NO;
 }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @ BraveS do you know how to get selected index on UIButton click event?

Comment: @VinayakB, Hi, I didn't use that lib for 2 years and don't remember what and where